# BotFramework Testing without downloading emulator

Tags: botframework

I've written a bot and am testing it locally on my machine through the bot emulator. However, my copywriting team want to be able to test it too but don't have the technical skills to set up the emulator.

Is there an easy way I can do this through maybe a Heroku review app (as that is how we currently distribute our app for testing)?

Comment: Is it deploying the bot to Azure an option?

Comment: I don't see what the problem could be. installing the emulator is just an exe you have to double click. doesn't even have a wizard. and if you use ngrok to create a public address for connecting to the bot they can get started in a few minutes. Install -> start -> paste link -> click connect = testing. The emulator would even be better than deploying it because they can reset the conversation more easily if needed.

Comment: They can test it but you should publish your bot somewhere. :)

Comment: @Xeno-D Would I have to be running the code locally on my machine though? I'm worried about it erroring and me having to manually restart it.

Comment: @EzequielJadib we're not use Azure at the moment, we are using Heroku

Comment: @SophieHebdidge Errors won't crash the bot. Whenever an exception is thrown in the bot the conversation is terminated and the next message from your tester will initialize a new conversation. Normally the only thing your users will see is a message "An exception has occurred."

Comment: @Xeno-D Interesting, normally I get a message that says "Woops, something went wrong" and then it doesn't receive any new messages until I restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a test page for them with the [Web Chat control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channels/channel-webchat).

Here's the HTML for one of my chatbots:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pig Latin Bot</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body style="font-family:'Segoe UI'">
    <img src="images/PigLatinBot.png" alt="Pig Latin Bot"/>
    <h1>Pig Latin Bot</h1>
    <p>Translates your text to Pig Latin.</p>

    <div id="webChatControl">

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#webChatControl").load("api/WebChat");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the controller code:

```
public class WebChatController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        string webChatSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebChatSecret"];

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BOTCONNECTOR " + webChatSecret);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(request);
        string token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        token = token.Replace(""", "");

        return $"<iframe width='400px' height='400px' src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/PigLatinBotJoeMayo?t={token}'></iframe>";
    }
}
```

There's a more detailed explanation in my blog post, [Using the Bot Framework Chat Control](http://blog.botcontext.com/2016/04/09/using-the-bot-framework-chat-control/).